# Use cases for using multiple queries for Spark Structured streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a requirement of streaming from multiple Kafka topics[Avro based] and putting them in Greenplum with small modification in the payload.

The Kaka topics are defined as a list in a configuration file and each Kafka topic will have one target table.

I am looking for a single Spark Structured application and an update in the configuration file to listen to new topics or stop. listening to the topic.

I am looking for help as I am confused about using a single query vs multiple:

```
val query1 = df.writeStream.start()
val query2 = df.writeStream.start()

spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

or

```
df.writeStream.start().awaitAnyTermination()
```

Under which use cases multiple queries should be used over the single query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you can use regex pattern for consuming the data from different kafka topics.

Lets say, you have topic names like "topic-ingestion1", "topic-ingestion2" - then you can create a regex pattern for consuming data from all topics ending with "*ingestion".

Once the new topic gets created in the format of your regex pattern - spark will automatically start streaming data from the newly created topic.

Reference:
[https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#consumer-caching]

you can use this parameter to specify your cache timeout.
"spark.kafka.consumer.cache.timeout".

From the spark documentation:

> spark.kafka.consumer.cache.timeout    - The minimum amount of time a
> consumer may sit idle in the pool before it is eligible for eviction
> by the evictor.

Lets say if you have multiple sinks where you are reading from kafka and you are writing it into two different locations like hdfs and hbase - then you can branch out your application logic into two writeStreams.

If the sink (Greenplum) supports batch mode of operations - then you can look at forEachBatch() function from spark structured streaming. It will allow us to reuse the same batchDF for both the operations.

Reference:
[https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#consumer-caching]

Comment: thanks for taking interest. I have only one target/sink i.e Greenplum but each topic payload will have it's corresponding table in GP. So should I have different queries for each topic or a single one. Will running multiple queries has benefit over single one. Right now, I am using a single query and inside foreachBatch, I am doing select(TOPIC).distinct.forEach to get topic vise data and then geting table name from topic for writing to jdbc. Is this a good approach?

Comment: Every time you call the writeStreams.start() - it will trigger a new independent streaming query (Which consumes more resources). So, foreachBatch() Sink - is the ideal way if you want to process the data once and write the output to multiple sinks

Comment: Hi @JDev, Did that clarify your question ?!